# here-map initialization giving MISSING_LIBRARIES under onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error)

Tags: android, here-maps-rest

Here is the code for here-map initialization.

```
        if (m_mapFragment != null) {
        /* Initialize the SupportMapFragment, results will be given via the called back. */
            m_mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error) {

                    if (error == Error.NONE) {
                        m_map = m_mapFragment.getMap();
                        isMapReady = true;
                        posManager = PositioningManager.getInstance();

                        // Register positioning listener
                        posManager.addListener(
                                new WeakReference<PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener>(positionListener));
                        if (posManager != null) {
                            posManager.start(
                                    PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK);
                        }
                    /*
                     * Get the NavigationManager instance.It is responsible for providing voice
                     * and visual instructions while driving and walking
                     */
                        m_navigationManager = NavigationManager.getInstance();

                        final VoiceCatalog voiceCatalog = VoiceCatalog.getInstance();
                        voiceCatalog.downloadCatalog(new VoiceCatalog.OnDownloadDoneListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDownloadDone(VoiceCatalog.Error error) {
                                if (error == VoiceCatalog.Error.NONE) {
                                    // Get the list of voice packages from the voice catalog list
                                    List<VoicePackage> voicePackages = voiceCatalog.getCatalogList();
                                    // select
                                    for (VoicePackage vPackage : voicePackages) {
                                        if (vPackage.getMarcCode().compareToIgnoreCase("eng") == 0) {
                                            if (vPackage.isTts()) {
                                                vid = vPackage.getId();
                                                    voiceCatalog.downloadVoice(vid, new VoiceCatalog.OnDownloadDoneListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onDownloadDone(VoiceCatalog.Error error) {
                                                            if (error == VoiceCatalog.Error.NONE) {
                                                                // set the voice skin for use by navigation manager
                                                                VoiceGuidanceOptions voiceGuidanceOptions =
                                                                        m_navigationManager.getVoiceGuidanceOptions();
                                                                voiceGuidanceOptions.setVoiceSkin(voiceCatalog.getLocalVoiceSkin(vid));
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(SpeedMediatorActivity.this,
                                "ERROR: Cannot initialize Map with error " + error,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

I'm getting in Error object->>

> Native libraries missing: gnustl_shared, gnustl_shared, gnustl_shared. Please refer to the user guide for details about proper project setup.
>   Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

did u follow the tutorial of the here maps engine? Like did u import the libraries correctly? I think the problem lies with the importing of the library

1. Did u add in the manifest
2. Did u extract and then unzip the content into the android app libraries?
3. Did u missed out any steps?

Comment: the day before yesterday, it was working fine. i added voice instruction too, worked fine. after sometime suddenly started throwing error like MISSING_LIBRARIES.

Comment: Have u tried 

1. clean project
2. rebuild project
3. invalidate cache and restart?